# fullcalendar. How to express time?

Tags: python, django, fullcalendar

I tried to make event using fullcalendar. However, it makes only all day schedule without time. I wanted to know how to change

start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',

to format like '2018-04-07T10:00:00'. Now it just make date format only.

start_date has information of both date and time. I am using python Django framework.

Thank you in advance.

```
  events: [
               {% for i in events %}
                     {
                        resourceId:'{{i.resource_id}}',
                        title: '{{ i.event_name}}',
                        start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                        end: '{{ i.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}',
                      },

               {% endfor %}

               ],
```

Comment: sounds like a python issue rather than a fullCalendar issue - you need to get python to output the data in the correct format. I added the right tags so hopefully those with knowledge of the language/framework will be able to help. I'm surprised you can't just google something like "django date format" though and find out for yourself. I googled it and the first link is https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/555/how-to-format-datetime-objects-in-the-view-and-template-in-django - I'm sure you can figure it out from there?

Answer (score 1):

New in Django 1.2, there is a template tag that will output what you wish:

```
{{ value|date:"c"}}
```

From the [Django template documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

Answer (score 0):

```
events: [
    {% for i in events %}
    {
        title: "{{ i.event_name}}",
        start: '{{ i.start_date|date:"Y-m-d"}}T{{i.start_date|time:"H:i" }}',
        end: '{{ i.end_date|date:"Y-m-d" }}T{{ i.end_date|time:"H:i" }}',
    },
    {% endfor %}
]
```

Try with those time (T)formats.